# Disable reminder notification for past events on macOS

Tags: calendar, notifications, reminders

I have an event defined on my Mac to remind my to go home on time.

Unfortunately, if I shutdown the Mac before the time of the reminder, I get a notification the next day as soon as I login.

Is there a way to only show reminders when they are actually on time, and not several hours later?

I totally get why this behaviour could be ok for some cases, but each event where I set a reminder it will not help me at a later time …

Comment: I also would like to stop this behavior. It is annoying to have to clear out events from the day before, especially if it's already been acknowledged from my iOS devices using the same Apple ID. I mean, that is what unified notifications is supposed to be for.